# Creating 32bit RGBA images

Tags: image, alpha, rgba

What is a free program that can create images and save them in 32bit RGBA format for OpenGL?

Or should I just convert them all in python?

Comment: Do you mean `PNG` RGBA files? Or plain, straight RGBA with no header?

Comment: I don't know to be honest, I guess something that openGL can read

Answer (score 0):

You can do that readily with ImageMagick - available for free for Windows, Linux and OS X. It is included in most Linux distros - try `convert -version`. On OSX, install with `homebrew` using `brew install imagemagick`.

```
# Create 32-bit RGBA image 2 pixels wide and 5 pixels high
convert -size 2x5 xc:"#1A2B3C80" -depth 8 fred.rgba 

# Check with "xxd" grouping in 4 bytes (1 RGBA pixel)
xxd -g 4 -c 8  fred.rgba
0000000: 1a2b3c80 1a2b3c80  .+<..+<.
0000008: 1a2b3c80 1a2b3c80  .+<..+<.
0000010: 1a2b3c80 1a2b3c80  .+<..+<.
0000018: 1a2b3c80 1a2b3c80  .+<..+<.
0000020: 1a2b3c80 1a2b3c80  .+<..+<.
```

If you have an image like this, for example

[image]

and you wanted the lime green to become transparent and it to be a 32-bit RGBA `PNG` file, you could do:

```
convert input.png -transparent lime PNG32:out.png
```

to give this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have windows 7 by the way, but can this be used to convert an rgb image (.png, jpg or bmp) to an rgba image, and select one colour to have an alpha of 0?

Comment: Yes, please  have another look.

Comment: Right I managed to find a .exe file and install imagemagick, but I can't convert any of the images in the Image folder that came with it.

Comment: Can you do `identify -version`? And `convert rose: a.jpg` and `convert rose: a.png`?

Comment: I can do `identify -version`:  gives `imagemagick 6.9.0-5 Q16 \times 64 2015-01-31 http:www.imagemagick.org`, copyright, `Features:DPC Modules OpenMP` , `Delegates <built-in>: bzlib cairo freetype jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr openexr pangocairo png ps rsvg tiff webp xml zlib`. But when I do `convert rose: a.jpg`, I get `convert.exe: unable to open image 'rose': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2674. convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format '' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501. convert.exe: no images defined 'a.jpg' @ error/convert.c/CopnvertImageCommand/3212.`

Comment: I don't know what is going on with your installation - `convert rose: a.jpg` should always work. Try converting any `jpg` into  a `tif` or `png` like this... `convert anyImage.jpg junk.tif` or `convert anyImage.png junk.png` to see if your `convert` is working at all. Then try the first example in my actual answer.

Comment: Hmmm... I would try removing what you have done so far, then installing either the `portable` or the `static 32 bit` version since they are more self-contained and more likely to work.

Comment: Ok I installed the static 32 bit one, but when I write `convert difference.png: difference.jpg` or something like this, I get `Invalid Parameter - difference.jpg`

Comment: Remove the colon (`:`) - that is only used with dummy, built-in images. Just do `convert a.png b.jpg`

Comment: All right, I closed and opened the command prompt aswell, now I'm getting the original error with `blob.c` etc.

Comment: I am confuzzled. I can only suggest you try the portable version instead.

Comment: Ah, thanks for your help. Something's wrong, I'd better try something else

Answer (score 0):

Paint.net works great - just need to create an image with two or more layers, make one layer transparent, then save it as a 32 bit png.